# jqplot and legend option issue

Tags: jqplot

I have the following in my code. Having the option

```
 legend: {show:true}
```

messes up the chart badly. The legend section is so long 
and there is no chart. 
 I have pasted the image here of how the chart looks : 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eqgbgy&s=7

It shows fine without the legend option though, but chart is of course without the legend.

In Chrome I see the following exception 
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        line2 = [['Living Expenses',1000], ['Loans',2000], ['Credit 
Card',500]]; 
    $j(document).ready(function() { 
        $j.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true; 
        $j.jqplot('piechartdiv', [line2], { 
            title: 'Where is my money going?', 
            seriesDefaults:{renderer:$j.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
rendererOptions:{sliceMargin:8}}, legend:{show:true} 
        }); 
}); 

</script> 

<div style="width: 450px;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    <div id='piechartdiv'></div> 
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Are you using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or some other CSS reset library?

If you go into firebug, and select the `<table class="jqplot-table-legend" ...>` element, you'll probably see that there is a `width:100%` default property set the `table` elements. You can fix it in your CSS layout:

```
#piechartdiv table.jqplot-table-legend {
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer to OP's question. I had this issue, and indeed my CSS styles indicated a 100% width for all tables, which broke the legend.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that seems weird to me is this:

```
$j.jqplot
```

Why are there some **J**'s on your code?, besides that, everything seems to be fine, maybe try putting a location on the legend to see if that fix the issue, here is an example:

```
plot = $.jqplot('chart2', [arr], {
        grid: {
            drawBorder: true,
            drawGridlines: false,
            background: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'e'
        }
    });
```

Comment: the $j's are probably just an alternative name for jQuery or $ because of compatibility with other libraries that use the $ sign

Answer (score 1):

I came across something similar.
try checking css property text-align:left

```
<div id='piechartdiv' style="text-align:left;"></div>
```

I'm afraid I don't know why but these fixed the error for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the jqplot.css file in your code.

Make sure that it is included in the code, and that the file is also present in the directory you are referring to.

Thank you